# Changing icon of wxToolBarToolBase on toggle event

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a toggle button in a `wxToolBar`.

I'd like the button to show two different icons according its state (one icon when it's "pressed" and another when it's "released").

I tried this:

```
// toolbar setup:

muteBtn = toolBar -> AddCheckTool(
      ID_MUTE_BTN,
      wxT( "Mute" ),
      wxBitmap( wxT( "unmute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ),
      wxBitmap( wxT( "unmute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ),
      wxT( "Enable/Disable sounds" ),
      wxT( "Enable/Disable sounds" )
);

...

// EVT_BUTTON handler:
void MyFrame::MuteChanged( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    if ( event.IsChecked() )
    {
        Mute();
        muteBtn -> SetNormalBitmap( wxBitmap( wxT( "mute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ) );
    }
    else
    {
        Unmute();
        muteBtn -> SetNormalBitmap( wxBitmap( wxT( "unmute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ) );
    }
    // also tried refresh and update without success:
    // toolBar -> Refresh();
    // toolBar -> Update();
}
```

but the behavior is not the one I expect. Instead of:

- startup icon: unmute.png
- after first click: mute.png  (`Mute()` called)
- after second click: unmute.png  (`Unmute()` called)
- after thirth click: mute.png  (`Mute()` called)
- ...

I got:

- startup icon: unmute.png
- after first click: unmute.png (`Mute()` called)
- after second click: mute.png (`Unmute()` called)
- after thirth click: unmute.png (`Mute()` called)
- ...

It seems that inside the event handler I change the icon but the bitmap is drawn only at the next click event.

I also tried adding `wxToolBar::Refresh()` and `wxToolBar::Update()` [see snippet] withouth success.

How can I get the correct behaviour?

Comment: I made a patch for the toolbar sample and submitted this ticket: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16985

Comment: @VZ.I guess this may be a bug in wxsidgets. Could you / someone suggest me an alternate way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers of wx confirmed that `wxToolBarToolBase::SetNormalBitmap()` should not be used.

I solved the problem by using the method `wxToolBar::SetToolNormalBitmap`:

```
// EVT_BUTTON handler:
void MyFrame::MuteChanged( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    if ( event.IsChecked() )
    {
        Mute();
        toolBar -> SetToolNormalBitmap( ID_MUTE_BTN, wxBitmap( wxT( "mute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ) );
    }
    else
    {
        Unmute();
        toolBar -> SetToolNormalBitmap( ID_MUTE_BTN, wxBitmap( wxT( "unmute.png" ), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wrong in my (now removed) comments and this is the right way to do it.